# Triboelectric Nano-Generator

Tags: electrostatics

[image]

I was studying about how could we generate electricity using triboelectric nano-generators, the thing which was confusing to me was why the aluminum balls are shown to have a positive charge whereas the surrounding enclosure bears a negative charge.
Do we have to start with an already charged object or I am missing something?

Comment: Link to the picture?